# How can I daw a playing board with the help of python

Tags: python-3.x

Create a function that takes in two parameters: rows, and columns, both of which are integers. The function should then proceed to draw a playing board (as in the examples from the lectures) the same number of rows and columns as specified. After drawing the board, your function should return True.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. As it stands, this question is likely to be downvoted or closed as it shows little to no effort. SO is not a code writing service and most people will be unwilling to solve your homework questions for you. For better results, show the code you have attempted, and what exactly is the issue you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

```
def tictactoeboard(rowsorcolumns):
rowsorcolumns = int(rowsorcolumns)
# Number of rows and columns have been equated to keep a square tic-tact-toe board
if (rowsorcolumns) < 3 or (rowsorcolumns) > 21:
    print("The number of rows or columns must be at least 3 OR at most 20")
    return False
    # For my screen, a comfortable size is that with 13 rows and columns
else:
    for rows in range(rowsorcolumns):
        if rows != rowsorcolumns-1:
            for columns in range(rowsorcolumns):
                if columns == 0:
                    print("__", end="")
                elif columns != 0 and columns != rowsorcolumns-1:
                    print("|__", end="")
                else:
                    print("|__")
        else:
            for columns in range(rowsorcolumns):
                if columns == 0:
                    print("  ", end="")
                elif columns != 0 and columns != rowsorcolumns-1:
                    print("|  ", end="")
                else:
                    print("|  ")
    return True
```

tictactoeboard(input("Enter the number of rows OR columns that you want for the board = "))

Answer (score 0):

```
def Game_Board(rows, columns):
    max_columns = 100
    max_rows = 50
    rows = int(rows)
    columns = int(columns)
    if columns <= max_columns and rows <= max_rows:
        for r in range((rows-1)*2+1):
            if r%2 == 1:
                print("-"*(2*columns-1))
            else:
                print(" |"*(columns-1))
    else:
        print("rows and columns are above table values")
    return

Print_Board = Game_Board(50, 100) 
print(Print_Board)
```

Comment: A textual explanation of the answer would make it more useful to future readers

Answer (score -1):

## Creating a playing board

def playingBoard(row, col):

```
for r in range(row):
    if r % 2 == 0:
        for c in range(1, col):
            if c % 2 == 1:
                if c != 5:
                    print(" ", end=" ")
                else:
                    print(" ")

            else:
                print("|", end=" ")
    else:
        print("--------")
```

row = 5`enter code here`
col = 6
print(playingBoard(row, col))